# WPF .NET 4.5 Gestures

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm currently developing an application for WPF that needs to run on Windows 7/8.  I would like to leverage some of the gesture features (TappedEventArgs, HoldingEventArgs, etc.) as found in the Windows.UI.Input namespace.  I am currently executing against .NET 4.5.

I am not seeing any of these gestures.  Am I missing something?  All I see are Manipulation events which means I would have to hand-code all of these gestures!  I did find a framework that someone wrote which seems like a decent alternative, but it hasn't been updated in awhile (Blake.NUI).

**Answer**

I answered my own question after doing some research into the differences between WinRT, WPF, and Silverlight. The answer is that unless you are writing a WinRT application, you are once again stuck in the land of deprecated UI frameworks from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question after doing some research into the differences between WinRT, WPF, and Silverlight. The answer is that unless you are writing a WinRT application, you are once again stuck in the land of deprecated UI frameworks from Microsoft.

Comment: I might not understand what you are looking for. But imo WPF has a pretty good [Touch support](http://www.ningzhang.org/2010/10/08/touch-support-in-wpf/).